# DOM: How to target same tag elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a document with a structure similar to:

```html
<section>
    <div>
        1
    </div>
    <div>
        2
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div>
        3
    </div>
    <div>
        4
    </div>
</section>
```

Without adding id's or classes how to can I target each div, let's say div 2 and 4?
P.S. sections/divs are dynamically added i.e. their count can change at any given time.

Comment: `nth-*` selectors. If you need to target elements with special value, check `.innerText`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the elements using `querySelectorAll()`, then use *index* to get the specific element.

**Demo:**

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('section > div');
var second = els[1].textContent.trim();
console.log(second);
var fourth = els[3].textContent.trim();
console.log(fourth);
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        1
    </div>
    <div>
        2
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div>
        3
    </div>
    <div>
        4
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to initially say that the count of the elements changes dynamically i.e. the current second section might become fourth in the future etc.

Comment: @PetromirKolev, then how you want to access the elements (like on clicking)?

Answer (score 1):

Use querySelectorAll and `last-child` and loop through the list.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("section > div:last-child").forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
</section>

<section>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
</section>
```